# Intellisense for Java classes in NativeScript

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I'm using some native Android code in my NativeScript project where I use few Java classes (like `StringBuilder` or `InputStreamReader`). I installed `tns-platform-declarations` and I have intellisense for Android stuff (or at least some of it), but not for these pure Java classes.

I use them currently like this:

```
let out = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
let sr = new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
```

The problem is I don't get any intellisense on for example `InputStreamReader` constructor overloads and parameters nor on `read()` method used on it later. `StringBuilder` and `InputStreamReader` are of type `any` here.

Is it possible to have the intellisense for all Java classes in NativeScript and Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the ReadMe of the plugin,

Create `reference.d.ts` and add the following content:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I had this file in my project but named `references.d.ts`. I'm not sure if this was the cause. I also then removed `declare var java: any;` from top of the file and now intellisense works.
Though if I leave `ios.d.ts` line in `reference.d.ts` file I get `node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts(170,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'NativeScriptEmbedder'.
node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios/objc-x86_64/objc!NativeScriptEmbedder.d.ts(2,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'NativeScriptEmbedder'.`
I don't need ios for now though.

Comment: I think `references.d.ts` should be still fine, `declare var java: any;` should have been the issue in your case. That declaration statement is used when you don't have to include platform declarations, just to prevent compiler errors without intellisense.